# An OP repeats his/her question after acknowledging an answer

Tags: discussion

I have noticed users repeating their questions after acknowledging an answer by posting a comment (that can range from agreeing to just neutral-type commenting).

The comment repeats almost to a T the same question again. This can be quite annoying. Often, this is accompanied by statements like: What about X where the entire thing has already been explained.

What should the answering poster do? :)

Comment: Can you link to some examples?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/178639/cavaliers-are-lakers-are-knicks-are-etc-vs-cavaliers-is-lakers-is/178647#178647 Not only do these posters sometimes repeat the question, they repeat their erroneous idea(s) about what it "should be". :)

Answer (score 2):

I would treat these comments in the same way as other comments that serve no purpose.  Flag them for deletion.

Comments in the SE system are meant to be ephemeral, so flagging them as *No longer required* should be acceptable.  Alternatively, a custom flag stating that they the comment just restates the question would work.

As a moderator on another SE site, I see such flags from time to time.  I will always delete comments of this nature.

Comment: So,not an answer=doesn't work. very low quality or mod.intervention then? One of those?

Comment: You're flagging a comment.  So *Not an answer* or *Very low quality* aren't options.  Using those flags on the answer itself would not be appropriate.

Comment: My question is: which item do you use here then? What is appropriate?